# MS Graph teams api cann't post message to channel and get channel's messages

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/team_id/channels/channel_id/messages
```

to get messages in channel and post message to channel, but I get an error when I want to get these messages

> UnknownError

When I post messages to channel , it shows `Unauthorized`.

My code

```
$headers = array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Authorization: Bearer {$_SESSION["access_token"]}",
);

$post_params = json_encode(array(
  "body"=>array("content"=>"Hello World")
));
```

Azure Permission

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Have you validated whether the logged on user has the necessary permissions/Azure AD Roles defined, so that he can perform the operation?

Comment: Check the token at https://jwt.ms to see whether the user has necessary scopes/permissions in it or not.

Comment: From your token analysis, I guess you should be using the client credential flow. When you grant delegated permissions, you need to use auth code flow or Ropc flow to obtain tokens. see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: OK,I will try it in my free time!!Let me get back to you~

Comment: Hi,Have you tested it? How is the result?

Comment: sorry, I was busy recently.Not yet tested....

Comment: @Kiwi  You can accept answers that are helpful to you to end the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This api only supports `delegated permissions`, you need to grant `ChannelMessage.Read.All` delegated permissions, and then grant `admin consent` for the permissions.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Comment: OK,thanks for reminding.But I have granted this permission , but nothing change...Do you want to confirm code?

Comment: @Kiwi  Please see my comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Several APIs including "List Channel Messages" are Protected APIs. It doesn't matter whether your admin gave you permission or not. Microsoft itself must give you permission too.

More info

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis#:~:text=Microsoft%20Teams%20APIs%20in%20Microsoft,before%20you%20can%20use%20them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Teams%20APIs%20in%20Microsoft,before%20you%20can%20use%20them).

Permission request form (Yes I know the form below looks ridiculous unfortunately that's the only way you request permission, the link is also given in the page above)

https://aka.ms/teamsgraph/requestaccess

Comment: so,if I want to use it,I must apply for microsoft?

Comment: @Kiwi Yes, you must to tell them why your app needs access to these APIs and what are you going to do with those data, and even whether or not you are going to keep the data or not e.t.c

Comment: OK,thanks very much.If I pass all questions.I just follow the document to use it?

Comment: Yes, I did it myself, if they approve documentation is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the list of channel messages via GRAPH with right permission (ChannelMessages.Read.All) and if you use the BETA endpoint of it. This is not a good idea for production btw but will solve the issue so you dont need to request this from MS.

For this you have to request the endpoint with a loggedIn user. (Delegated)